# Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php, database, data-binding, pdo, code-snippets

I just learn to use PHP PDO and have the following problem :

```
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
```

The error refer to this code :

```
if( $this->_query->execute() ){
```

Here is my code:

```
public function query($dbUse='', $sql, $params = array(), $datatypes = array(), $orderby='', $limit=''){
    $this->_error = false; //always first initialize to false

    /* Check which DB will be used */
    $this->_pdo = $this->_pdoPostgres;

    $FlagSelectWithCount = ( substr($sql, 0, 6) == 'SELECT' ? true : false );

    if( $FlagSelectWithCount ){ // received SELECT statement
        if( $this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare( "SELECT COUNT(*) as computedrow FROM ( {$sql} ) AS X", array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL) ) ){

            $x = 1;
            if( count($params) ){
                foreach($params as $param){
                    $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                    $x++;
                }
            }

            if( $this->_query->execute() ){
                $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

                foreach ($this->_results as $obj){
                    $this->_count = $obj->computedrow;
                }

                if($this->_count){
                    if( $this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare( $sql . $orderby , array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL) ) ){

                        $x = 1;
                        if( count($params) ){
                            foreach($params as $param){
                                $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                                $x++;
                            }
                        }
                        if( $this->_query->execute() ){
                            $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                        }else {
                            $this->_error = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else{
                    $this->_count = 0;
                }

                //$rows = $this->_query->fetchColumn();
                //$this->_count = count($rows); //for select

            } else {
                $this->_error = true;
            }
        }
    }
    else{

        if( $this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare( $sql ) ){

            $x = 1;
            if( count($params) ){

                foreach($params as $param){
                    $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param, $datatypes[$x-1]);

                    $x++;
                }
            }
            //$this->_pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            //$this->_pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

            if( $this->_query->execute() ){
                $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
            } else {
                $this->_error = true;
            }
        }
    }
    /*
    if( substr($sql, 0, 6) == 'SELECT' ){
        $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ( {$sql} ) AS X";
    }

    //$sql = "SELECT * FROM user_profile WHERE user_name='husni'";
    if( $this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ( {$sql} ) AS X", array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL) ) ){
        //echo "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ( {$sql} ) AS X";
        $x = 1;
        if( count($params) ){
            foreach($params as $param){
                $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                $x++;
            }
        }

        if( $this->_query->execute() ){

            $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            echo $rows = $this->_query->fetchColumn();
            echo ' tryCount'.count($rows);
            $this->_count = count($rows); //for select
            //echo ' countReturned--'.$this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount(); //for other than select
            //echo '--';
        } else {
            $this->_error = true;
        }
    }
    */

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the actual *$sql* and *$params* arguments that lead to the error? Does your SQL have just as many question marks in it as the parameter array has elements?

Comment: *"The error refer to this code :

if( $this->_query->execute() ){"* - Um... there's 3, which one?

Comment: `FROM ( {$sql}` you're not trying to bind a table, are you? If so, you can't.

Comment: I think he is just injecting the *$sql* contents there to make a count query. The binding happens later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that you have fewer question marks (unnamed tokens) in your *$sql* string than elements in the *$param* array passed to your function.

You could add this test in your code, which would output a message when they are not equal:

```
if (substr_count($sql, "?") != count($param)) {
    printf ("Error: SQL has %d tokens, while %d parameters were provided.",
            substr_count($sql , "?"), count($param));
}
```

The test is not bullet proof, because you could have question marks within string literals: those would be erroneously counted.

But this could serve its purpose in debugging your code.

NB: You can write your loops using `$x =>`

like this:

```
foreach($params as $x => $param){
    $this->_query->bindValue($x+1, $param);
}
```